# No Pictures - Really?

Tags: police, photography

In order to fly out of Pereira, Colombia, today, I was forced to do a
full-body x-ray.  I was allowed
to see the x-ray and it was very detailed, showing bones and internal
organs, but I was not allowed to take a photo of the image.  I wanted the
photo for my own benefit since I've had some stomach problems lately
(and for future comparisons) and since I had already "suffered" the x-ray
radiation.

Can I legally fight the photo denial?  Is there a way to either
succesfully take a photo next time or to sue the government?  My thinking
is that the forced image of my body belongs more to me than to the police.

I imagine that this question is hard to answer for Colombia, so would
accept an answer which would apply in case this ever happened in
California, USA.

Comment: Are you using "forced" in a legal sense? Did you have the option not to fly?

Comment: Yes, I had the option not to fly.

Comment: @bobuhito I imagine this question is relatively easy to answer for Colombia, but not as far as I'm aware by any regular contributor to this site.  Perhaps we can recruit a Colombian lawyer to join and answer.  Does anyone here have fluent Spanish?

Comment: Whatever your rights to your own personal data according to Colombian law, in many counties there are laws forbidding taking pictures in security sensitive areas (and certainly a police control in an airport would usually qualify). And while you may argue that your picture would not have been a security risk, the safe action for the police officer is to prevent you from taking. Also, they do not want people disturbing them and letting the place while they still have to inspect lots of other passengers.

Comment: And in any case medical imaging devices are VERY carefully calibrated in order to provide consistent images between different machines and people. Short of a live or death emergency with no other option available, I cannot imagine any radiologist agreeing to make a diagnosis on the basis of a snap picture of the screen of a machine not intended for medical imaging.

Comment: Yes, the photo would be more for my own curiosity and amusement, but most photos have value exactly for that.  It sounds like everybody is saying I have no chance of legally getting the photo or winning a lawsuit...which was my suspicion too.  That being said, if I were head of Colombia police, I actually would allow the x-ray subject to get an emailed copy of the image if they chose to (it's basically no extra cost/time for the police and would be a good public gesture providing one more souvenir for tourists).

Comment: *"basically no extra cost/time"* - this is evidently false to anybody who has dealt with arranging a high volume of individual emails internationally. How are you getting the photo to the server, especially from a device never intended for it? What about their details? What privacy laws do you have to worry about? (hint: **all of them**) and where do you find, in an understaffed underfunded department, the effort and resources to do all of this in a secure way?

Comment: @Nij It's small compared to the cost/time of the x-ray itself.  I'm not saying it's zero and I understand your points, but I disagree with it being significant in comparison (as an analogy, which seems fitting here, one x-ray in Colombia per year is not significant to the total radiation I already receive...but I still didn't want it because it isn't really zero!).

Comment: The x-ray has to happen. The email doesn't. Wasting more police money and time on what is a frivolous novelty for tourists, with the addition of far more bureaucracy (that you still underestimate the size of!)? Don't be silly.

Comment: @Nij Please notice the USA and Europe stopped backscattering x-rays in airports (which have far less radiation than the x-rays used on me), so things are not as clear-cut as you are making them sound.  My idea to allow the passenger to receive their image was simply a comment and not part of the question anyway.

Comment: Unless I'm much mistaken, Colombia is not in Europe, and I am not aware of any current active invasion/annexation by the USA, so until Colombian authorities decide otherwise, this doesn't seem relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This paper](https://www.ipc.on.ca/wp-content/uploads/Resources/wholebodyimaging.pdf) (Canadian author, but references from across North American and Europe) suggests an answer - the scanners are configured so every image is deleted immediately after use.

It's not that airport authorities are keeping pictures of you to which you're entitled - quite the opposite. As a privacy measure no one - including both you and the airport authorities - is entitled to make or retain a copy of the image.

Not only would there be no legal basis to insist on a copy, you would be asking for something that ceased to exist the moment you left the security area.

Comment: You might be able to argue the privacy point somewhat, but I had my camera ready to take a picture before anything got deleted (and was stopped).

Comment: I'm going to take the lack of other answers to mean that no one sees a way to get a picture (or simply to get out of the x-ray and still fly) in the future and mark this as the answer...but let me wait a few more days.

Comment: @bobuhito - If there's a policy of not retaining pictures there wouldn't be a practical (let alone legal) way to obtain a copy, and most airports I've experienced don't permit passenger photography in the security area. Flying without a scan might be possible (for example the "enhanced body search" mentioned here : https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/information-on-the-implementation-of-security-scanners), but this is likely to be subject to airport and jurisdiction - it would be wise to call and ask the airport first.